# What's the process of producing coffee oil from green beans?

Tags: whole-bean

How to make coffee oil? It's something obvious that can be done at home? What's the process in general?

Comment: Could you provide a little background? What is coffee oil, and how might it be used?

Comment: Coffee beans contain natural oils which are activated by heat application. On wikipedia we can read: During roasting one of these oils, [caffeol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee#Roasting), is created at about 200 °C (392 °F), which is largely responsible for coffee's aroma and flavor.

Comment: I've heard that coffee oil has many uses.

Comment: Interesting question; looking forward to seeing the answers myself. Good luck getting an answer, and welcome to Coffee.SE!

Answer (score 3):

Ehow seems to have a [step-by-step walkthrough](http://www.ehow.com/how_5824318_extract-coffee-oil-coffee-bean.html) for extracting coffee oil.

Essentially, it seems you slow cook coffee beans in olive oil, then strain the oil through cheesecloth.